Linq how can do null check in where clause?
This is simple linq query
datetime dob = "05152024";
var query = from row in maxLookupData.AsEnumerable() 
     where row.Field<DateTime>("bar")) <=  dob 
select row;

In above query
If one of the row.Field("bar") value is null, I want to replace null value with "dob".
How can I do that. I tried something like this no luck
datetime dob = "05152024";
var query = from row in maxLookupData.AsEnumerable() 
     where row.IsNull(Field<DateTime>("bar")? dob ) <=  dob 
select row;

How can I handle this null check ?

You want to replace it with startDate, or dob? Because with your second code block you're doing where dob <= dob, which is always true. How about restating the filter as "if the "bar" field is null, include the entry, otherwise only include the entry if the bar field's value is less than or equal to dob"?

In addition, you've tagged this "ado.net", but you have a .AsEnumerable() from your source collection. Did you intend this query to be translated into SQL and ran on the database itself? Otherwise, "ado.net" isn't relevant here as this is a pure in-memory LINQ code problem.

I'm also guessing maxLookupData is something like a DataTable, given the use of the Field<>() call and such.

Are you trying to filter the data (which is what where is for) or trying to project different data if the field is null?

Perhaps the field type be given as DateTime? and use ?? as the null coalescing operator, as in where (row.Field<DateTime?>("bar") ?? dob) <=  dob.

Other possibilities (closer to what you were attempting): where (row.IsNull("bar") ? dob : row.Field<DateTime>("bar")) <= dob or where row.IsNull("bar") ? true : (row.Field<DateTime>("bar") <= dob)

Linq is not designed to modify data within a query. You can filter the data or return new data, but if you want to change the data you will need to loop through the rows and set the column value on each relevant row.  Whether you look through the datatable directly or through a projected collection of DataRows, the change would be done in the loop, not in the Linq query:
foreach (DataRow row in maxLookupData.Rows)
{
    if(row.IsNull("bar"))
        row["bar"] = dob;
}

There's no simple mechanism to query the datarows and replace one column value with a Linq query.

Might try something like this if your are still looking to use Linq. But yes like others have said Linq is used to get filter data down not really to change values directly.
datetime dob = 050162024;
foreach (var r in maxLookupData.Where( x => x.YourField == null).ToList())
        r.YourField = dob;

